# EF Core Migration Adding Tables from Other Contexts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to create a 1..1 relationship between two tables (CustomerProfile & ProviderProfile) and a main ASP.NET Core `IdentityUser` table (AppUser). When I run the migration all tables are being generated from each of the schemas (each of the 3 tables have their own Schema setup) inside of the AppUser Schema (Users).  Here is how the `IdentityContext` is configured:

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, string>
{
    private const string schema = "Users";

    
    public DbSet<CustomerProfile> CustomerProfile { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProviderProfile> ProviderProfile { get; set; }

   public override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.HasDefaultSchema(schema);

        builder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasOne(x => x.ProviderProfile)
            .WithOne(x => x.User)
            .HasForeignKey<ProviderProfile>(x => x.UserId);
        
        builder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasOne(x => x.CustomerProfile)
            .WithOne(x => x.User)
            .HasForeignKey<ProviderProfile>(x => x.UserId);
    }
}
```

Here is the AppUser (IdentityUser) class definition:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public bool IsServiceProvider { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerProfile CustomerProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual ProviderProfile ProviderProfile { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the migration the database Users schema as a crap ton of tables form the other DbContexts that hold references to `CustomerProfile` and `ProviderProfile` in turn which have all those tables as well (where they're supposed to live).

To provide more detail:  The CustomerProfile and ProviderProfile both have their own DbContext's and have references to several other tables in them (these related tables belong to the schema's for each profile).  The tables in each of the profiles belong to the same schema as the Profile classes. Those Entites/Tables are the culprits that are being generated in the Identity schema (Users) of which they do not belong.

There are 3 schemas:

1. Users (IdentityContext - Users schema)
2. Customers (CustomersContext - Customers schema)
3. Providers (ProvidersContext - Providers schema)

So, users context has 1..1 relationship w/ both Customers and Providers tables.

CustomersContext has several tables related to customers
ProvidersContext has several tables related to providers

It is the tables in the Customers + Providers constext's that are getting dumped into the Users (IdentityContext) schema

Comment: Can you describe your problem in detail, did you migrate to generate other dbcontexts?

Comment: Does ignoring references to other entities in `OnModelCreating` not work?

Comment: @Yinqiu - updated the question with a bit more detail.

Comment: @abdusco - I suppose I can add them to the ignore list - but is this really necessary ?  I thought EF was sophisticated enough to know they aren't part of the schema.

Comment: @abdusco - that seemed to work.  Do you want to add that as an answer and i'll mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever EF comes across a property in an entity class `A` that references `B` class, it adds a new relation that connects both.

```cs
class Student {
    public School School { get; set; } // <-- many-to-one relation
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; } // <-- many-to-many relation
    // ...
}
```

This happens [by convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#conventions) and requires no involvement from the developer.

> By default, a relationship will be created when there is a navigation property discovered on a type. A property is considered a navigation property if the type it points to can not be mapped as a scalar type by the current database provider.

If you want to prevent EF Core from interpreting these properties as relations, you need to tell it explicitly to [ignore those properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=fluent-api%2Cwithout-nrt#included-and-excluded-properties) and EF won't try to map them to DB.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
        .Ignore(e => e.CustomerProfile);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I presume I can still call on the relation and get the CustomerProfiles using EF ?  i.e. - `context.AppUser.Profiles.Where(x => x.Id == 1);`

Comment: More like `context.Profiles.Where` or `context.Set<Profile>().Where` on the context where `Profile` entity is registered.